# Get the text inside a p-tag and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How do you guys get the text inside a **p tag** and store it in a variable in VueJS?

Because right now, it just displays it in a **p tag** but I want the text inside the p tag to be stored in a  variable for later use.

Below is my html code

```html
<b-form-input v-model="search" placeholder="Search by disease"></b-form-input>

<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="result in filteredPeople(search)" :key="result.LONG_D" :value="{ id: result.LONG_D, text: result.ICD_C }">{{ result.LONG_D }}</option>
</select>
<p>
  Value: {{selected.id}}
</p>
<b-button class="btn" variant="success" v-on:click="runAPI(search)">Search</b-button>
```

And this one is my JS code.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: {},
      search: "",
      msg: null,
      selected: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    runAPI: function(disease) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:9000/api/disease/" + disease)
        .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
      console.log(this.results);
    },


    filteredPeople() {
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        return this.results.filter(item => {
          return item.LONG_D.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
        });
      } else {
        return this.results;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to put a function in the tag that takes the value (it could also of course return the value so the display wouldn't change). The function could then store the value in a data or local variable and you would have it.
like so:

```
 {{getSelectedId(selected.id)}}
```

anything inside `{{}}` is JS so you can have functions and even use logic (although not so recommended to put too much logic in template).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this . 
**JS CODE**

```
 export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: {},
      search: "",
      msg: null,
      selected: ""
    };
  },
 methods: {
runAPI: function(disease) {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:9000/api/disease/" + disease)
    .then(response => (this.results = this.filteredPeople()))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  console.log(this.results);
},


filteredPeople() {
  if (this.searchQuery) {
    return this.results.filter(item => {
      return item.LONG_D.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
    });
  } else {
    return this.results;
  }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<select v-model="selected">
   <option
    v-for="result in results"
    :key="result.LONG_D"
    :value="{{ id: result.LONG_D, text: result.ICD_C }}">{{ result.LONG_D }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Will it store the value of LONG_D in a variable?

Comment: Yess should be , then also check it out .

Comment: How can store result.LONG_D in a variable other than making a function like Michael's answer

Comment: Change your js code as i do and check out the result . @learn2code